# Copying data from one workbook into a userform on another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, userform

I am trying to save time inputting data by transferring data from one workbook, into another (preferably, straight onto a userform that I have initiated the copy from).

So I have a button my form which initiates the below;

```
Sub CopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open("SOURCEWORKBOOKPATH")
wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("CELLNAME").Copy

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
UserForm_Initialize
wbTarget.Forms("UserForm1").Range("DESTFORMFIELD").PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues

wbThis.Close
UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
```

I have managed to copy from one workbook to another workbook fine, however I want the data copied into the form textboxes.

It's erroring on

```
wbTarget.Forms("UserForm1").Range("DESTFORMFIELD").PasteSpecial
```

but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way.

Store the copied value in a variabe

```
cell_content = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("CELLNAME").Value
UserForm1.DESTFORMFIELD.Value = cell_content
UserForm1.Show
```